# Why can I not delete Google Markers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, maps

I have methods of rendering Markers as shown below. I'm passing markers array from props and rendering it each time componentDidUpdate triggered. The problem is my old markers is not removing from maps. For example if I had 1 coordinates inside my parent component and update it with new ones, the new one appears and the old one stands still.

```
`
import React from 'react';

const google = window.google;

export class GMap extends React.Component {
  mapRef = React.createRef();
  directionsService
  directionsRenderer
  map;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initMap();
    const { onClick } = this.props;

    onClick && this.onMapClick();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { markers } = this.props;

    this.calcRoute();
    if (markers && markers.length > 0) {
        this.clear(markers);
        this.renderMarkers(markers);
    }
  }

  initMap() {
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    const mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: { lat: 40.386119, lng: 49.860925 }
    }
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    this.map = map;
    this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  }

  onMapClick() {
    this.map.addListener('click', (e) => {
        this.props.onClick(e);
    })
  }

  renderMarkers(markers) {
    markers.forEach(position => {
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position });
        marker.setMap(this.map);
    })
  }



  calcRoute() {
    const { directions } = this.props;

    if (directions) {
        const [{ lat: fLat, lng: fLng }, { lat: tLat, lng: tLng }] = directions;

        if (fLat && fLng && tLat && tLng) {
            var request = {
                origin: { lat: fLat, lng: fLng },
                destination: { lat: tLat, lng: tLng },
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };
            this.directionsService.route(request, (result, status) => {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        }
     }


  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div id='map' ref={this.mapRef} />
    )
  }
```

}

```
`
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you removing the markers? All I can see in the posted code is `this.clear(markers)` with no reference to `clear`. Try doing something like this:

```
clear(markers) {
  for(let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but in this case all map are being cleaned but then cannot add a new marker..

Comment: Why'd not be able to add new markers afterwards? Please can you share a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this from our side?

Comment: Here is the link for codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-meadow-vx7iz?file=/public/index.html

Comment: Please do not forget to provide api_key in index.html

Comment: Great thanks Mammad, I'll take a look today and get back to you.

Comment: Ok so I'm unable to load the map at all even after adding the maps script with my valid API key, please can you double check that the codesandbox is working on your end?